# Why Crypto++ library's AES definition is so fast

Tags: encryption, aes, cpu, optimization

I am trying to compare the CPU cycle required for two encryption algorithms. One algorithm is AES and lets the other algorithm is B(code name). I implemented algorithm B and having fewer and simpler operations than AES and expected to take much less time/CPU cycles per encryption than AES

I am using an Intel i3, 10 gen processor, with 4MB cache. I am running both algorithms individually (with random 16-byte input) for $2^{20}$ times and taking the minimum and maximum required CPU cycles.

I see that for algorithm B CPU cycles are `minimum=2707866` and `maximum=4767402`. But, for crypto++ definition of AES, the CPU cycles are `minimum=2724` and `maximum=29978194`. I have performed the test multiple times and the results are almost similar. It is clear that the maximum time required for AES is much higher(7x) then algorithm B, but the minimum time for AES is much less.

I then recorded required CPU cycles for all $2^{20}$ AES encryption. I found that the first encryption is taking maximum cycles (`29978194`) and then the required CPU cycle reduced drastically and after 10-15 encryption it took almost same(`approx 3000`) CPU cycles for each encryption. For algorithm B every encryption took almost the same CPU cycles.

I do not understand the drastic reduction(10000 times) of CPU cycles for AES encryption(crypto++ library). Is there any voodoo of AES-NI? Can someone tell what kind of optimization is being done there?

Comment: What _exactly_ are you measuring? AES encryption of a single block? With or without key expansion? On what CPU _exactly_ (unfortunately Intel's naming for 10th Gen encompasses two quite different microarchitectures)? What are the cycle counts you gave us? For all $2^{20}$ runs summed? For each operation?

Comment: The key schedule doesn't take that long (even if they don't use the AES-NI key scheduling instruction)

Comment: @SEJPM I am measuring the number of CPU clock pulse required for one block full-round encryption. Key expansion is included in the measurement. I have given the maximum and minimum required CPU cycle count of $2^{20}$ runs. Where each run does one full round encryption.

Answer (score 5):

**Actually, your numbers seem shockingly high at 2724 cycles for *one* block - even with the key schedule.**

Crypto++ uses standard AES-NI for the encryption of blocks and for the key generation they use AESKEYGENASSIST for the SBox (unfortunately).

Ideally the expected performance would be (for their implementation, not for one with an optimized on-the-fly key expansion):

- ~783 cycles for the keyschedule ([as estimated by llvm-mca](https://godbolt.org/z/cxrob3))
- 1x 1 cycle for the initial XOR of the key
- 10x 4 cycles for AESENC/ AESENCLAST

So overall less than 1000 cycles.

Even if we assume AES-256 here, we shouldn't get beyond 1500 cycles for the actual operations. 2700 is massively off from that and suggests inefficiencies in feeding AES data.

Also note that this kind of test is highly unfair to the AES-NI hardware because it only really shines if you give it 4 or more independent AES operations to calculate in parallel (due to latency of 4 cycles per round instruction but the throughput of 1 cycle per instruction). Furthermore note that Crypto++'s keyschedule implementation is ... rather lackluster, and optimized implementations compute a round key in less than 20 cycles, so less then 200 overall for the entire cipher.

You can find the [translated key expansion code here](https://godbolt.org/z/7esKnr). You can look the performance of the instructions up either at [Intel's site](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#othertechs=AES) or in [Agner Fog's tables](https://www.agner.org/optimize/).

---

A fairer comparison would probably take the best non-AES-NI implementation, a AES-NI implementation of AES and an optimized implementation of your cipher and put them up against each other in these categories:

- CBC encryption of long messages - measures the cipher latency and long messages "hide" the key schedule cost
- CTR encryption of long messages - measures the maximal throughput
- (Optionally) Stand-alone keyschedule computations with one encryption (which is roughly what you measured) - with an implementation optimized for fast key schedules (aka not Crypto++ as it currently stands)

Comment: I originally intended to actually count the cycles taken for the keyschedule until I saw the mess that is the generated machine code and simply asked llvm-mca to do it for me. If they actually used an optimized key expansion I probably would have counted manually.

Comment: I run the test for some more numbers of time. Each time after restarting the machine. 1217 was the best results. BTW, if I want to compare two ciphers what should be the parameters if not this.

Comment: @Radium I have added a section about better scenarios.

Comment: @SEJPM AES-NI could you explain the _unfortunately_?

Comment: @kelalaka the use of AESKEYGENASSIST Iis unfortunate because it takes quite a while to compute (like 20 cycles latency and 8 CPI throughput) while doing operations which are rather easily done faster with aesenclast.

Answer (score 2):

AES has highly optimized implementations, including additions of special instructions to intel CPUs specifically for AES. but even without it is amazing how much optimization can go into the implementation og an algorithm it's quite an art.

I also have doubts in your measurements, the maximum may be only noise from context switches etc.

AES can be implemented to be very very fast hundreds of MBs per second on a modern CPU. It will be hard to beat with something you implement even if the algorithm is fundamentally more efficient

---

Software AES-256-CBC performance on OpenSSL

```
openssl speed aes-256-cbc
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 34522867 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 8989219 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 2263537 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 536651 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 68886 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256 cbc for 3s on 16384 size blocks: 34381 aes-256 cbc's in 3.00s
```

AES-NI AES-256-CBC performance on OpenSSL where available with evp

```
openssl speed -evp aes-256-cbc
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 16 size blocks: 128709647 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 64 size blocks: 46266772 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 256 size blocks: 11740574 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 2953460 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 368469 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
Doing aes-256-cbc for 3s on 16384 size blocks: 181790 aes-256-cbc's in 3.00s
```

Approximately 5x speed up.

Comment: I agree with your points. I also think that it may be the noise and context switching that is playing dirty with the clock pulse measurements. But, it made me shocked that how the minimum clock is that much low. I just tested that AES full round encryption is taking the approx same time as performing 4 simple additions. That is why I am not understanding the Crypto++'s optimization funda.

Comment: It probably uses hardware acceleration, Special CPU instructions for AES. you can't compete with that.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#:~:text=An%20Advanced%20Encryption%20Standard%20instruction,Advanced%20Encryption%20Standard%20(AES).